# Android Sqlite subquery is not returning all intended results

Tags: android, sql, sqlite, android-studio

I am working on a learning app which retrieves data from a local sqlite database. That database has two tables.

1. The `category` table which stores the article categories:

```
+-------------+--------------------------+
| category_id | category_value           |
+-------------+--------------------------+
| programming | How To Start Programming |
+-------------+--------------------------+
| math        | How To Start Math        |
+-------------+--------------------------+
| chemistry   | How To Start Chemistry   |
+-------------+--------------------------+
```

2. The `article` table which stores the articles themselves:

```
+-------------+------------+------------------------+
| parent_id   | article_id | article_value          |
+-------------+------------+------------------------+
| programming | java       | Let's learn java       |
+-------------+------------+------------------------+
| programming | python     | Let's learn python     |
+-------------+------------+------------------------+
| math        | funcs      | Let's learn functions  |
+-------------+------------+------------------------+
| math        | derivative | Let's learn derivative |
+-------------+------------+------------------------+
| chemistry   | lewis      | Let's learn Lewis      |
|             |            | structure              |
+-------------+------------+------------------------+
```

Now I did implement a search ability. I want the results to be either the articles who has the searched phrase in their `article_value` or the ones who has the searched phrase in their parent's `category_value`. So I used this query in order to do so:

```sql
SELECT * FROM article WHERE article_value LIKE '%search_phrase%' OR parent_id = (SELECT category_id FROM category WHERE category_value LIKE '%search_phrase%')
```

It works fine for the articles part but when it comes to the subquery part it only returns the articles of just one category. Even if there are more qualified categories.

Comment: can you please share one of the search_phrase which is not giving correct result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does a `LEFT JOIN` do what you want?

```
SELECT a.*
FROM article a LEFT JOIN
     category c
     ON c.category = a.article_parent AND
        c.category_value LIKE '%search_phrase%'
WHERE a.article_value LIKE '%search_phrase%' OR 
      c.category IS NOT NULL;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with EXISTS:

```
SELECT a.* FROM article a 
WHERE a.article_value LIKE '%search_phrase%' 
OR EXISTS (
  SELECT 1 FROM category c
  WHERE c.category_id = a.parent_id
  AND c.category_value LIKE '%search_phrase%'
)
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/pfqYEpFnszeP5YJM4faBr7/0).